# Can I customize outlook add-in header?

Tags: xml, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I'm making Outlook add-in and trying to customize the heading section.

I learned that I can change text and Icons but can I customize it beyond that (like changing layout, adding buttons...)?

Also, I cannot separate header text from ribbon button text (both of them are set by the DisplayName XML tag in the manifest). How can I set the different text to the button in the ribbon?

[question 1 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSj7d.png)

[question 2 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi43d.png)

I tried setting different text using Label tag inside Group tag but button still uses the text from DefaultValue attr in DisplayName tag.

below is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>c53b418c-ae64-45f0-81b8-5e9c054de036</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="test"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="I love newjeans"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3090/assets/icon-64.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3090/assets/icon-128.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.newjeans.com/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://www.newjeans.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3090/outlook.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read"/>
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="OutlookButton.Label"/>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="OutlookButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="OutlookButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="OutlookButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Outlook.Url"/>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3090/assets/icon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3090/assets/icon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3090/assets/icon-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Outlook.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3090/outlook.html"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="I love newjeans"/>
        <bt:String id="OutlookButton.Label" DefaultValue="hello?"/>
        <bt:String id="ActionButton.Label" DefaultValue="I love newjeans"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="OutlookButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="I love newjeans"/>
        <bt:String id="ActionButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="I love newjeans"/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```